# Why is my JLabel (ImageIcon) giving me an error when i try to rotate it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

I am programming a game and when he go left the image should rotate left but it is not it is giving me and error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Schoo.NewGame.TheRealGame.turnPlayer(TheRealGame.java:365)
at Schoo.NewGame.TheRealGame$2.run(TheRealGame.java:154)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Yes, i know that java.lang.NullPointerException means something is null but nothing ***should*** be null anyway here is the code on line 365:

```
g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
```

line 154 just runs the method:

```
public static void turnPlayer(Direction d){
    Graphics g = playerImage.getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (d == Direction.LEFT){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    if (d == Direction.UP){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    if (d == Direction.RIGHT){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    if (d == Direction.DOWN){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    RepaintPlayer();
    f.repaint();
    playerImage.repaint();
}
```

and if you need the whole class:

```
public class TheRealGame{

private static boolean running = false;
private static boolean paused = false;
private static boolean right = false, left = false, up = false, down = false;
private static JFrame f;
private static ArrayList<JLabel> ae = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
private static Player p;
private static Playere pt;
private static JLabel playerImage;
private static boolean info = false;
private static JLabel iy, ix, im, in, iu;

public static void main(Playere playertype){
    pt = playertype;
    p = new Player(pt);
    f = new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(700, 700);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                up = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                left = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                down = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                right = true;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                p.attack();
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F3){
                if (info == true){
                    info = false;
                    iy.setVisible(false);
                    ix.setVisible(false);
                    im.setVisible(false);
                    in.setVisible(false);
                    iu.setVisible(false);
                }else if (info == false){
                    info = true;
                    iy.setVisible(true);
                    ix.setVisible(true);
                    im.setVisible(true);
                    in.setVisible(true);
                    iu.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                up = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                left = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                down = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                right = false;
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                p.attack();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
    iy = new JLabel();
    ix = new JLabel();
    im = new JLabel();
    in = new JLabel();
    iu = new JLabel();
    iy.setLocation(0, 10);
    ix.setLocation(0, 20);
    im.setLocation(0, 30);
    in.setLocation(0, 40);
    iu.setLocation(0, 50);
    iy.setBounds((int) iy.getLocation().getX(), (int) iy.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    ix.setBounds((int) ix.getLocation().getX(), (int) ix.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    im.setBounds((int) im.getLocation().getX(), (int) im.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    in.setBounds((int) in.getLocation().getX(), (int) in.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    iu.setBounds((int) iu.getLocation().getX(), (int) iu.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    f.add(ix);
    f.add(iy);
    f.add(im);
    f.add(in);
    f.add(iu);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setTitle("free play - tokyo ghoul");
    Start();
    p.Paint();
}
public static void resume(){
    if (paused == false){
        return;
    }
}
public static void pause(){
    if (paused == true){
        return;
    }
}
public static void Stop(){
    if (running == false){
        return;
    }
    running = false;
}
public static void Start(){
    running = true;

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int last = 0, u = 0;
            while (running == true){
                if (paused != true){
                    if (up == true){
                        p.move(p.getX(), p.getY()-1);
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.UP){
                            turnPlayer(Direction.UP);
                        }
                    }
                    if (down == true){
                        p.move(p.getX(), p.getY()+1);
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.DOWN){
                            turnPlayer(Direction.DOWN);
                        }
                    }
                    if (left == true){
                        p.move(p.getX()-1, p.getY());
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.LEFT){
                            turnPlayer(Direction.LEFT);
                        }
                    }
                    if (right == true){
                        p.move(p.getX()+1, p.getY());
                        if (p.getDirection() != Direction.RIGHT){
                            turnPlayer(Direction.RIGHT);
                        }
                    }
                    if (info == true){
                        int l = 10-last;
                        iy.setText("y: "+p.getY());
                        ix.setText("x: "+p.getX());
                        im.setText("enemys: "+ae.size());
                        in.setText("next enemy: "+l);
                        iu.setText("Updated "+u+" times.");
                        RefreshInfo();
                    }
                    if (p.getY() == -337){
                        p.move(p.getX(), 337);
                    }
                    if (p.getY() == 337){
                        p.move(p.getX(), -337);
                    }
                    if (p.getX() == -349){
                        p.move(349, p.getY());
                    }
                    if (p.getX() == 349){
                        p.move(-349, p.getY());
                    }
                    RepaintAllLabels();
                    Enemy.UpdateAll();
                    if (info != true){
                        f.repaint();
                    }
                    if (last == 10){
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int x = 1+r.nextInt(2), y = 1+r.nextInt(2), distance = 1+r.nextInt(570), nx = 0, ny = 0;
                        if (x == 1){

                        }
                        last = 0;
                    }
                    last++;
                    u++;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void RefreshInfo(){
    f.remove(iy);
    f.remove(ix);
    f.remove(im);
    f.remove(in);
    f.remove(iu);
    f.add(ix);
    f.add(iy);
    f.add(im);
    f.add(in);
    f.add(iu);
    iy.setLocation(0, 10);
    ix.setLocation(0, 20);
    im.setLocation(0, 30);
    in.setLocation(0, 40);
    iu.setLocation(0, 50);
    iu.setBounds((int) iu.getLocation().getX(), (int) iu.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    iy.setBounds((int) iy.getLocation().getX(), (int) iy.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    ix.setBounds((int) ix.getLocation().getX(), (int) ix.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    im.setBounds((int) im.getLocation().getX(), (int) im.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    in.setBounds((int) in.getLocation().getX(), (int) in.getLocation().getY(), 100, 15);
    f.repaint();
}

public static void UpdateAll(){

}

public static void Paint(JLabel imgs, int x, int y, File file){
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
    imgs.setBounds(x, y, img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight());
    imgs.setLocation(x, y);
    imgs.setVisible(true);

    f.add(imgs);
    imgs.setVisible(true);
}

public static void Repaint(JLabel l){
    f.remove(l);
    l.setBounds((int)l.getLocation().getX(), (int)l.getLocation().getY(), l.getWidth(), l.getHeight());
    f.add(l);
}

public static void addAE(JLabel l){
    ae.add(l);
}

public static void RepaintAllLabels(){
    for (int i = 0; i < ae.size(); i++){
        Repaint(ae.get(i));
    }
}

public static void MovePlayer(int x, int y){
    playerImage.setLocation(x, y);
    playerImage.repaint();
    f.repaint();
}

public static void RepaintPlayer(){
    if (p.isAttacking()){
        if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_hit.png"));
            playerImage = new JLabel(img);
        }
        if (pt == Playere.Touka){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_hit.png"));
            playerImage = new JLabel(img);
        }
    }else{
        if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/Kaneki_walk.png"));
            playerImage = new JLabel(img);
        }
        if (pt == Playere.Touka){
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/Schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png"));
            playerImage = new JLabel(img);
        }
    }
    playerImage.setVisible(false);
    playerImage.repaint();
    playerImage.setVisible(true);
    playerImage.repaint();
    playerImage.setVisible(true);
    MovePlayer(p.getX(), p.getY());
    f.repaint();
}

public static void paintplayer(){
    if (pt == Playere.Kaneki){
        playerImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/kaneki_walk.png")));
        if (playerImage == null){
            System.out.println("[ERROR THIS WAS THE ERROR THE WHOLE TIME!!");
            return;
        }
        ImageIcon imgs = new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/kaneki_walk.png"));
        playerImage.setBounds(p.getX(), p.getY(), imgs.getIconWidth(), imgs.getIconHeight());
        playerImage.setLocation(0, 0);
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
        f.add(playerImage);
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
    }
    if (pt == Playere.Touka){
        playerImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")));
        playerImage.setBounds(p.getX(), p.getY(), new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")).getIconWidth(), new ImageIcon(StartMenu.class.getResource("/schoo/NewGame/touka_walk.png")).getIconHeight());
        playerImage.setLocation(p.getX(), p.getY());
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
        f.add(playerImage);
        playerImage.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void turnPlayer(Direction d){
    Graphics g = playerImage.getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (d == Direction.LEFT){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    if (d == Direction.UP){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    if (d == Direction.RIGHT){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    if (d == Direction.DOWN){
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.DOWN){
            return;
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.LEFT){
            g2.rotate(90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.UP){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0);
        }
        if (p.getDirection() == Direction.RIGHT){
            g2.rotate(90.0+90.0+90.0);
        }
        p.setDirection(d);
        playerImage.repaint();
    }
    RepaintPlayer();
    f.repaint();
    playerImage.repaint();
}

public static enum Direction{
    LEFT, UP, RIGHT, DOWN;
}
}
```

Thank you for taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/). This class does all the rotation logic for you. You just need to specify the degrees of rotation.

So the basic code to create the label would be:

```
RotatedIcon icon = new RotatedIcon( new ImageIcon(...) );
JLabel player = new JLabel( icon );
```

Then when you want to rotate the Icon you can use:

```
icon.setDegrees(...);
player.repaint();
```

Comment: Still does not rotate though.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you do Swing Graphics -- you shouldn't be calling `getGraphics()` on a component since there is great risk that the object will either be null or non-functioning. Instead if this were my program, I'd get the actual image used, rotate it in all 4 directions (3 plus the original), make ImageIcons out of these images, store them in a collection, or better a `HashMap<Direction, Icon>`, say called playerDirectionIconMap, and then use them without fear. Then to get the proper icon, I'd just call something like,

```
// this method should probably not be static
public void turnPlayer(Direction d){
    playerImage.setIcon(playerDirectionIconMap.get(p.getDirection()));
    // .... other code?
}
```

Note that the `turnPlayer(...)` method should not be static as this suggests a broken design that needs to be fixed.

Also note that:

- The rotate method uses radians and not degrees, so instead of 90.0, use `Math.PI / 2`.
- You will want to use the rotate method that takes a center point so that your rotation isn't around 0, 0.

Comment: So are you telling me instead add a Icon to the frame ?

Comment: @Rof: No -- you add an Icon to your JLabel, here your playerImage JLabel, just as you're already doing.

Comment: so `setIcon(TheIcon)`?

Comment: @Rof: your statement and code above confuses me as it is out of context. Please look at the code in my answer above to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks no error but it still does not rotate?
And about that note: if it is static nothing works

Comment: @Rof: 1) note that rotation uses radians, not degrees, 2) that you need to specify a rotational center point. 3) and re "nothing works" because your design is broken. You need to create OOP compliant objects first, even before creating your GUI, otherwise you're placing the cart before the horse -- letting a bad design control the creation of your program.

Comment: @Rof: also, when debugging such things, try to do so in a separate small program, one that is separate from the main large program. This will make debugging (and asking questions on this site) much easier.